# MessageBox resizing bahavior depending on the size of the Text string

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, messagebox

Hi i am trying to implement the MessageBox resizing bahavior depending on the size of the Text (not caption) string in a custom DialogBox i am building in WPF. It's my custom MessageBox with the layout of my app.

But how MessageBox does to depending in the size of the string, the height of the MessageBox grows automatically? How to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how i normally do this:

```
<Window SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="NoResize" ...>
```

Additionally you could have a `ScrollViewer` as the child of the window and set the `MaxHeight` & `MaxWidth` properties on the window to restrict it further.

**Edit:** To give a discreet example of what the window might look like:

```
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
  ResizeMode="NoResize" MaxWidth="400" MaxHeight="400">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.Children>
          <FlowDocumentScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
          </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>

          <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <!-- Buttons -->
          </StackPanel>
    </Grid.Children>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: That is usefull in the Window and it's what i need for the Window. But which control i use to show the Text? I need a control that grows automatically depending on the length of the Text. And if the Textbox does that and i don't know how. If i want to the TexBox doesn't grow in Width, i only have to use the property TextWrapping. But and if i want it to let her grow in height? I don't have any idea which control is used in the MessageBox to show the Text...

Comment: You can create a `Page` as the window's content with a `FlowDocument` in it, then just can use all kinds of blocks and inlines to display text. If you want text to wrap **you need to set the MaxWidth** on a container, otherwise it just grows in width (normally until the window is as wide as the screen).

Comment: Actually a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` might be more appropriate from a simple message box, i added some more sample code.

Comment: But can the FlowDocumentScrollViewer grow to a certain limit (MaxHeight) like the usual MessageBox does?

Comment: You can set MaxHeight on any framework element, including the FlowDocumentScrollViewer if you want to.

Comment: I know that. What i am asking is if i can put some Text in the Control, and if it's too big let him grow up automatically depending on the Lenght of the Text (but when reaches the MaxHeight automatically appear the ScrollBar). Is that possible with the FlowDocumentScrollViewer?

Comment: Of course it is possible, just get bloody going and *use* it.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF you usually use the FormattedText class to finetune text.

What you need exactly if I got it right is the BuildGeometry method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.buildgeometry.aspx

So you need:

- Create you formatted text
- Build the geometry from it
- Extract the bounding box
- Resize you messagebox to this box size